# Does libspotify support oauth

Tags: spotify

I just downloaded the libspotify and was looking at the examples and learning more about it. I want to know does the current version of the libspotify support oauth? I have tried searching but didnt find anything so I'm asking here in case I'm missing an important link. My client says that instead of username and password for signing in to spotify they will give me a oauth token (taken from facebook I think) and through that I should be able to sign in. Please guide, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, your client is mistaken.

libspotify logs into the Spotify service using either Spotify or Facebook username/password credentials, and nothing else. You cannot log into Spotify with a Facebook OAuth token.

It's worth noting at this point - never save these details yourself - libspotify can remember them for you in its secure store.