# Libstpotify API - How can I use a single sign in process to connect to both Spotify and Facebook?

Tags: spotify

In my libspotify-based app, can I prompt the user for a **single sign-in** with his (Facebook) credentials to **connect both to Spotify and Facebook** ?

Scenario #1 could be :

- My libspotify-based app is also a registered Facebook app.
- User authorizes and connects to my app using his Facebook credentials.
- Thanks to that user session I would like to connect to his Spotify account
  Is that possible ?

Or Scenario #2... which goes against oauth security :

- User connects to my libspotify-based app with his facebook credentials (it works)
- the app somehow **- how ? -** gets Facebook session tokens
- the app uses those tokens to access authorized facebook info such as what the user's friend listen to and so on.
- the app uses those tokens to require more permissions ?

Or is there a better scenario so I can achieve this single sing-in process ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This login flow isn't possible with libSpotify — the user has to log in with a username or password, whether it's a Spotify or Facebook account and you can't extract a Facebook auth token from libSpotify once it's logged in.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. Is it something you plan to enable in the future ?

Comment: Related post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528982/does-libspotify-support-oauth)

Comment: An auth token allows a single application to access Facebook. Your application and Spotify aren't the same thing, so you need two separate access tokens. It's the same with the Apps API — apps running inside Spotify need to auth with Facebook independently of Spotify itself.