# Get facebook friends that also use spotify

Tags: ios, facebook, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm building an iOS app using the Spotify API that requires communication with my Spotify friends. I've come to realize that it's really facebook friends that also use Spotify and that to do that, you need to authenticate with facebook in order to get any sort of info like that. So the next few things I'm trying to figure out, but am getting stuck with are:

1. With the Spotify SDK, is there a way to tell if it's connected with your facebook account (since it's not required). And if so, do you have to do a separate authentication? I'm guessing yes.
2. With the facebook open graph api, is there a way to get a list of your friends that also use Spotify. I know that you can get friends using that have authenticated your app, but haven't found a way to find out about others. Not sure if it's possible.

Based on what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440689/libstpotify-api-how-can-i-use-a-single-sign-in-process-to-connect-to-both-spot) that what I'm trying to do isn't going to be possible. Or if it is a huge pain. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nope. However, with CocoaLibSpotify, if the user logs in with an email address you can be sure it's a Facebook account since vanilla Spotify usernames aren't email addresses.
2. Nope. You could look at each friend's public listens using the Facebook API, though, but that isn't ideal.