# LibSpotify login with oAuth Token

Tags: oauth, spotify, libspotify

I built a web app that (among other things) provides access to your Spotify library. For that I am already obtaining a [Spotify oAuth token](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) which works fine with their [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/).

My app will also allow you to stream your music to another device while controlling it from the web (or phone). For that I am sending the (encrypted) oAuth token to that device which will then use libSpotify to play that song.

Unfortunately, from what I can see, libSpotify can't authenticate with the oAuth token and [requires the plain text password instead](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/group__session.html#ga4533a992a120cacb109c892a852afe2a)? That would force me to additionally ask for the user's password (bad UX) and probably even store it myself (bad idea in general).

@Spotify is there a plan to change that and add support for login via oAuth token in libSpotify? Any other way to avoid asking for both, oAuth and plain text password from the user? The Android SDK accepts the oAuth token for playback.

P.S. I am aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528982/does-libspotify-support-oauth), but it is about the Facebook OAuth token and also quite old by now.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Spotify and got the following answer:

1. There are no plans on implementing this.
2. They are not accepting feature requests or bug reports for libSpotify.

Sounds a bit like it will be discontinued at some point. Anyways, to answer my question above: Spotify seems to force us to ask the user to authenticate via OAuth, then ask the user again for the plain text password.

I'd be happy to be proven wrong (maybe there's a way to get an OAuth token via libSpotify and the password?) Can't find anything there though..